# AWS ALB and HAProxy Keep-Alive header

Tags: amazon-web-services, haproxy, amazon-alb, keep-alive

Has any one come across this behavior?

- AWS ALB is sending traffic to HaProxy.
- HaProxy sets keep-alive header to 29 seconds.
- Client connected to ALB does not see this header.
- It can only see "Connection: keep-alive" header.
- Basically, ALB is stripping out keep-alive header.
- Enabling/Disabling HTTP/2.0 in ALB settings has no effect on this behavior.
- ALB idle connection timeout is more than 29 seconds.
- Occasionally client gets 502 error from ALB possibly because ALB tries to use a connection just before 29s window is over and HAProxy closes it in few milliseconds meaning that connection was idle for last 29 seconds.
- Is setting keep-alive timeout > ALB idle timeout the only solution here? Why would ALB not try to open a new connection if it receives a connection reset in this race condition?

Comment: It's 2024 and I still see this issue. Spring Boot application has "Keep-Alive: timeout=300" added to the response headers. I can see the header returned when I run it locally, but when deployed behind an ALB the Keep-Alive header is not received by the client. The ALB is HTTP/2 enabled, and I read that HTTP/2 prohibits that header, but you said here HTTP/2 or not doesn't make any difference, so...

Comment: Basically, ALB is saying that, let me manage the connection with the clients, so it removed the header set by the backend. We have observed that istio gateway also works in similar manner. The solution for us was to set idle timeout of ALB to be less than keep alive and idle timeout of backend, so that ALB will always close the connection first, so that there is no race condition when ALB initiates a new request.